# How can I get access to a Django Model field verbose name dynamically?

Tags: django, get, field

I'd like to have access to one my model field verbose_name.

I can get it by the field indice like this

```
model._meta._fields()[2].verbose_name
```

but I need to get it dynamically. Ideally it would be something like this

```
model._meta._fields()['location_x'].verbose_name
```

I've looked at a few things but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For Django < 1.10:

```
model._meta.get_field_by_name('location_x')[0].verbose_name
```

Comment: I get `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'` error. Django 1.7.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer: I don't know how to break this to you, but... strings don't have fields.

Comment: Well, it's model object which is passed in your snippet, and not string, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, which means that you need to pass a model too.

Comment: Well, and I do, I have template filter for that: `def verbose_name(value, arg): return value._meta.get_field_by_name(arg)[0].verbose_name` and in template: `{{ book|verbose_name:"title" }}`

Comment: How have you registered the filter?

Comment: Prepending `def verbose_name` with the decorator `@register.filter`

Comment: The `get_field_by_name` method was [removed for Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-10), plus using `get_field` suggested below looks less of a hack...

Answer (score 30):

`model._meta.get_field('location_x').verbose_name`

Answer (score 21):

For Django 1.11 and 2.0:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('my_field_name').verbose_name
```

More info in the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/)

Answer (score 14):

The selected answer gives a proxy object which might look as below.

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x{SomeMemoryLocation}>
```

If anyone is seeing the same, you can find the string for the verbose name in the *title()* member function of the proxy object.

```
model._meta.get_field_by_name(header)[0].verbose_name.title()
```

A better way to write this would be:

```
model._meta.get_field(header).verbose_name.title()
```

where `header` will be the name of the field you are interested in. i.e., 'location-x' in OPs context.

**NOTE**: Developers of Django also feel that using `get_field` is better and thus have depreciated `get_field_by_name` in Django 1.10. Thus I would suggest using `get_field` no matter what version of Django you use.

Answer (score 7):

```
model._meta.get_field_by_name('location_x')[0].verbose_name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
Model.location_x.field.verbose_name
```

Model being the class name. I tested this on my Animal model:

```
Animal.sale_price.field.verbose_name
```

Animal.sale_price returns a DeferredAttribute, which has several meta data, like the verbose_name

Note: I'm using Django 3.1.5

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate on all the fields you need to get the `field`:

```
for f in BotUser._meta.get_fields():
    if hasattr(f, 'verbose_name'):
        print(f.verbose_name)
```

Comment: Kudos. This is better than most solutions here! No beating around the bush (no need to specify any `field`). And is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
# select fields for bulk_update : exclude primary key and relational
fieldsfields_to_update = []
for field_to_update in Model._meta.get_fields():
        if not field_to_update.many_to_many and not field_to_update.many_to_one and not field_to_update.one_to_many and not field_to_update.one_to_one and not field_to_update.primary_key and not field_to_update.is_relation :
            fields_to_update = fields_to_update + [field_to_update.name]
Model.objects.bulk_update(models_to_update , fields_to_update)
```