# 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' error when trying to get access to a Model field verbose_name dynamically from template

Tags: python, django

Django 1.7

I have a model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(
        'Автор',
        max_length = 200, 
        blank = True
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        'Заглавие',
        max_length = 200
    )
    pub_year = models.IntegerField(
        'Год издания', 
        max_length = 4, 
        choices = YEAR_CHOICES
    )
```

In my `views.py` I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from books.models import Book
from forms import BookForm

class BookListView(generic.ListView):

    model = Book
    paginate_by = 25
```

I want to get `verbose_name`s of Book model fields in template. In order to do it I have registered template tag (function code is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429094/2947812):

```
@register.filter
def verbose_name(value, arg): 
    return value._meta.get_field_by_name(arg)[0].verbose_name
```

and in template I use it this way:

```
{{ book|verbose_name:"title" }}
```

As I can tell, everything is made according to [Django documentation on custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/).

But instead of verbose_name value, I get `'str' object has no attribute '_meta' error`. I guess that it's because instead of Book object, something other is passed to `verbose_name` function, but why?

Comment: show your view code please

Comment: @user2717954 There is `views.py` code in the post.

Comment: sorry i didnt know about ListView until this very moment but from reading the docs it seems you need to do {% for book in object_list %} {{ book|verbose_name:"title" }} {% endfor %}. is this how you try to access the variable book?

Comment: Well, I changed `book` to `book_list.0` and now it's OK. But if there will be no items in book_list, then I'll get another error...

Comment: Is this question still open? I have a similar question but your specifics seem inconsistent. Can you answer your own question or reformat this in some way that is more meaningful?

Comment: @WadeWilliams This particular question was only because of me being inattentive to my template's code, and it's answered by user2717954's comment. But what I want to accomplish in general is to get model's `verbose_name` from template, and I still don't know how to do it universally.

Comment: @WadeWilliams I've added an answer to this post to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly used `{{ book|verbose_name:"title" }}` without having variable `book` set. My template is for ListView, and `book` is set only within `{% for book in book_list %} ... {% endfor %}` loop. So I rewrote my template this way:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>{{ book_list.0|verbose_name:"author" }}</th>
            <th>{{ book_list.0|verbose_name:"title" }}</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for book in book_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```